# Access a particular row,column in a csr_matrix

Tags: python, scipy

I have a sparse matrix in csr format (which makes sense for my purposes, as it has lots of rows but relatively few columns, ~8million x 90).

My question is, what's the most efficient way to access a particular value from the matrix given a row,column tuple? I can quickly get a row using `matrix.getrow(row)`, but this also returns 1-row sparse matrix, and accessing the value at a particular column seems clunky. The only reliable method I've found to get a particular matrix value, given the row and column, is:

```
matrix.getrow(row).todense().A1[column]
```

But this seems overly verbose and complicated. Is there a simpler/faster method I'm missing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can get the value as usual from `matrix[row,column]`.

Comment: Wow...I was doing matrix[row][column] instead. Oops. Thanks!

Comment: same problem here, I guess I'm used to the C way! This should be much more upvoted, I think that lots of people stumble on this one...

Comment: Is this an O(1) operation ?